# scrollview restrict scrolling area ios Swift

Tags: ios, swift, scrollview

I have limited the area that my scrollview can scroll to already. I want to know if there is a way to stop scrolling all together after a certain point. Right now when it reaches the end I can scroll past the end by keeping my finger on the screen, is there anyway to restrict the scrollview so that it wont let me go past the end at all?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can disable bounce effect like this :

```
myScrollView.bounces = false
```

also set the content size of your scrollView with de desired size :

```
myScrollView.contentSize = CGSize(width: xxx, height: xxx)
```